# How to use Stirling's formula to derivate a finer large deviations upper bound on the IID case

Tags: probability, inequality

In page 3 of the paper [On a new law of large numbers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02795493), by Erdos and Renyi one reads:
[image]

where $$h(x) = x \log_2 \frac{1}{x}+(1-x) \log_2 \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

**Typo?**

There might be a typo here. Take $\gamma =1/2$
by the symmetry of the binomial coefficients together with $\sum_k {n\choose k} = 2^n$ we get that
$$\sum_{n/2\leq K\leq n} 2^{-n} {n\choose k} \geq 1/2 $$

Now since $h(1/2) = 1$. The upper bound inequality in  (2.6) of the paper becomes:

$$1/2\leq \sum_{n/2\leq K\leq n} 2^{-n} {n\choose k} \leq B_1n^{-1/2} \to 0 $$

which is in contradiction.

Is there an error  on (2.6) of the paper?

**Question**

If we required $\gamma$ to be strictly bigger than $1/2$ would such inequality hold?

How do we use Stirling formula in this case?

$${n \choose K} = \frac{n!}{(n - K)!K!} \sim \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi(n-K)K}}\bigg(\frac{n}{n-K}\bigg)^{n-K}\bigg(\frac{n}{K}\bigg)^{K}$$

But now, how do we sum this terms to get the desired inequalities (upper and lower bounds?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that, if $\gamma$ is a fixed contant greater than $1/2$, then
$$\sum\limits_{\gamma n \le k \le n} \binom{n}{k} = \Theta\left(\binom{n}{\gamma n}\right).$$
This is because each next binomial coefficient is constant-time smaller than the previous one:
$$\frac{\binom{n}{k + 1}}{\binom{n}{k}}  = \frac{n - k}{k + 1} \le \frac{1 - \gamma}{\gamma} < 1,$$
for $k \ge \gamma n$. Thus we can only analize the first coefficient in the sum. This can be done directly by Stirling's formula:
$$\binom{n}{\gamma n} \sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi\gamma (1 - \gamma) n}} \cdot 2^{h(\gamma)n},$$ as $n\to\infty$, and (2.6) follows (once again, for every fixed $\gamma > 1/2$).